# fork, execlp in Linux

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  int f1[2], f2[2];
  char buff;

  if(pipe(f1) != -1);
   printf("Pipe1 allright! \n");

  if(pipe(f2) != -1);
   printf("Pipe2 allright \n");



  if(fork()==0)
  {
    close(1);
    dup(f1[1]);
    close(0);
    execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);  
  }
  else
  {
    if(fork()==0)
    {  
    close(0);
    dup(f1[0]);
    close(1);
    dup(f2[1]);
     execlp("grep", "grep", "^d", NULL); 
    }
    else 
    {
        if(fork()==0)
        {
            close(0);
            dup(f2[0]);
            execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL); 
      } 
    }

  }

  return 0;

}
```

I am trying to do ls -l | grep ^d | wc -l in C.

I tried everythig...

What is wrong? :(

Output: Pipe1 allright!, Pipe2 allright!

Ps. Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

Comment: Is the 'Ps' addressed to us, or is it a reminder to self?

Comment: Why do you want to this by hand? Why don't you simply use `system("ls -l |grep '^d'|wc -l");` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

```
if(pipe(f1) != -1);
  printf("Pipe1 allright! \n");
```

I assume this should be a *real* error check, so please remove the `;` in the `if` line.

Running your program after that you will notice, that the `grep` and `wc` commands are still there, they don't terminate. Check this with the `ps(1)` command. The `ls` command seems to have terminated.

Let's assume, the pids of the four processes are :

- 9000 (main)
- 9001 (ls)
- 9002 (grep)
- 9003 (wc)

Looking into `/proc/9002/fd` you will see, that filehandle 0 (`stdin`) is still open for reading:

```
> ll /proc/9002/fd/0
lr-x------ 1 as as 64 2011-10-22 20:10 0 -> pipe:[221916]
```

And looking around, who has this handle still open with

```
> ll /proc/*/fd/* 2>/dev/null | grep 221916
```

you will see, that *many* handles to this pipe are open: both `grep` and `wc` have **two** of them open. Same is true for the other pipe handles.

Solution:

You have to close the pipe handles after `dup` *rigorously*. Look here:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     int f1[2];
     char buff;

     if(pipe(f1) != -1)
          printf("Pipe1 allright! \n");

     int pid = fork();
     if(pid==0)
     {
          close(1);
          dup(f1[1]);

          close(f1[0]);
          close(f1[1]);

          close(0);
          execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);  
     }
     printf("ls-pid = %d\n", pid);

     int f2[2];
     if(pipe(f2) != -1)
          printf("Pipe2 allright \n");

     pid = fork();
     if(pid==0)
     {  
          close(0);
          dup(f1[0]);

          close(f1[0]);
          close(f1[1]);

          close(1);
          dup(f2[1]);

          close(f2[0]);
          close(f2[1]);

          execlp("grep", "grep", "^d", NULL);
          // system("strace grep '^d'"); exit(0);
     }
     printf("grep-pid = %d\n", pid);

     close(f1[0]);
     close(f1[1]);

     pid = fork();
     if(pid==0)
     {
          close(0);
          dup(f2[0]);
          close(f2[0]);
          close(f2[1]);

          execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL); 
     }
     printf("wc-pid = %d\n", pid);

     close(f2[0]);
     close(f2[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to use dup2 instead of dup, that is, instead of

```
close(1);
dup(f1[1]);
```

do

```
dup2(f1[1], 1);
```

and so on for other occurencies

Comment: @Domiik: It's astonishing, that _this_ solves your problem. If I modify the code in the question, then there is still no output.